# signalr scale testing for broadcast messages using hubs

Tags: c#, .net, testing, signalr, scale

I have a very simple signalr Hub based application that basically sends out 1 single type of message periodically to around 1000 clients at a time.

I would like to be able to test that 1000 web browsers can connect and receive a message from the hub in a repeatable load testing environment.

I have seen that the signalr documentation shows how to load test using the `Crank` tool. But this has the limitation of not being able to test the Hub types of deployments, which is not helpful.

Has anyone seen how one might create instances of a hub and clients and test that X number of clients all received a message within a certain time frame?

Comment: are you load-testing the server or the client implementation?

Comment: the server component at this stage, but I also want to confirm that each client receives the message

Comment: in this case the easiest thing to do IMO is create a console client with multiple threads (tasks) connecting to your hub and run this in some virtualized environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment from zaitsman, I have come up with the following code which I would appreciate some feedback on?

```
[TestClass]
public class SignalRConnectionTest
{
    static AutoResetEvent _autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private const string HUB_URL = "http://mysite/signalr";
    private const string HUB_NAME = "chatHub";

    private static Dictionary<int, bool> _clientResponsesRecieved = new Dictionary<int, bool>();

    private static object lockObject = new object();

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestJoinHub()
    {
        const int numberOfClients = 10;

        var manualEvents = new ManualResetEvent[numberOfClients];

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfClients; i++)
        {
            manualEvents[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);

            var stateInfo = new State(manualEvents[i], i);
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ConnectToSignalRAndWaitForMessage, stateInfo);
        }

        foreach (var manualResetEvent in manualEvents)
            manualResetEvent.WaitOne();

        Assert.AreEqual(_clientResponsesRecieved.Count, numberOfClients);

        foreach (var key in _clientResponsesRecieved.Keys)
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(_clientResponsesRecieved[key]);
        }
    }

    class State
    {
        public int threadId = 0;
        public ManualResetEvent manualEvent;

        public State(ManualResetEvent manualEvent, int threadId)
        {
            this.manualEvent = manualEvent;
            this.threadId = threadId;
        }
    }

    private void ConnectToSignalRAndWaitForMessage(object state)
    {
        var stateInfo = (State) state;

        var hubConnection = new HubConnection(HUB_URL);
        var chatHub = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy(HUB_NAME);

        Console.WriteLine("Starting connection");

        hubConnection.Start().Wait();

        chatHub.On<string, string>("broadcastMessage", (username, message) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message Recieved: {0}", message);

            lock (lockObject)
            {
                _clientResponsesRecieved.Add(stateInfo.threadId, true);
            }

            stateInfo.manualEvent.Set();

        });
    }
}
```